# Missing property options in visual studios angular app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I'm following this tutorial to create an Angular project with .Net Core backend in Visual Studios 2022:

[Tutorial: Create an ASP.NET Core app with Angular in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022)

However, I am not able to follow step 3 of "Set the project properties" section as I couldn't find the debugging options in the properties.

[Set up project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022#set-the-project-properties)

[image]

Properties

[image]

Comment: can you correct the documentation url?

Comment: you need to open the properties of ASPNETcore

Comment: step 3 is for the angular app @Sajeetharan

Comment: Can you tell me your VS 2022 version, I have reproduced your problem on Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.0 Preview 1.0. This might be a document issue, I have submitted a feedback about it, and I will give you a reply if get any response.

Comment: @ZhiLv thanks! my version is VS Community 2022 17.1.1

Answer (score 2):

This is a known product bug that will likely be fixed shortly in a VS update.

The default path for the launch.json is under .vscode/launch.json. so if the launch.json is already there (all our templates put it there by default) then F5/debugging will work with no problems. So in most cases, the workaround is to just skip the step for accessing the config page.

[The document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022#set-the-project-properties) has been changed (add a note), you can check it.

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking at the solution's properties, not the project's properties?

This happens when you have selected your solution instead of your project.

You have 2 options:

```
Right click on your project in solution explorer and select "Properties"
Select your project in solution explorer and open Project -> Properties
```

Comment: I'm certain i've selected the Angular project properties (added a screenshot)